# Strange extra pair of parentheses in std::vector constructor?

Tags: c++

Could someone elaborate on why the extra pair of parentheses in the code below is necessary for correct compilation? We are creating an `std::ifstream` and reading everything from it into an `std::vector`... I see these parentheses in the examples on stack overflow, but I can't figure out why they would change the way the compiler interprets the code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream curFile("file.txt", std::ios::binary);

    std::vector<char> fileContents(
        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(curFile)),      //why?
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
    );
}
```

The parentheses I am talking about wrap the `istreambuf_iterator` constructor. Without them, the compiler seems to think that `fileContents` is a function declaration.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupes: In C++ `type(name)` in certain circumstances is treated as you just wrote `type name`.  That means you are naming a function parameter, not creating an object.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse is a good reference too.